# How to Allow SSL URL in Android error (No peer certificate)

Tags: android, eclipse, web-services, ssl

I try to use HTTPS for API url in my application Android send to webservice this following code:

```
public final class Constants {
    public static class Extra {
    public static final String api_url = "https://example.co.id/";
    public static final String PACKAGE_NAME = "example.co.id";
    public static final String token = "some token";
    }
   }
```

Why if i'm try to running aplication get error in log (No peer certificate), before my website already buy sertificate ssl in web hosting.

I try to search in google, try to search best practice, but i not get same for my case and use keystools i'm very not understand where im to start added SSL "**https**" in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Way to make android app to connect to URL is to skip the SSL verification (Only if we are sure about the connection)

For this you can add [this class](https://web.archive.org/web/20201204023258/https://newfivefour.com/android-trust-all-ssl-certificates.html) and execute it inside onCreate method

```
new NukeSSLCerts().nuke();
```

It will skip certificate verification by trusting all certificates.

Comment: if i skip verification by trusting all certificates it is more secure or not? please give me explain :) thanks! @Samrat Das and notice i not use onCreate becase just final class for definde api_url

Comment: im problem in HostnameVerifier() and SSLSession in function NukeSSLcerts(), how to fix that?

Comment: It will be secured untill, server is trusted. since server must have been developed by you. It is secured. and add
    
`import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;`
as header.

Comment: It's **less** secure. A secure connection requires *both* encryption and verifying that you're actually talking to who think you're talking to. The second part comes from talking to someone with a certificate you trust, or that's been trusted (signed) by someone you do trust, on and on until there's a verifiable chain of trust for the server you're talking to. Try getting a certificate using https://letsencrypt.org/ first.


Don't release your app to regular users with this part "nuked".

Comment: i see, and than what i start to fix it allow sertificate, im already using SSL in my webhosting. Because if i start application with "https" always No peer sertficate.